# How to know when gallery widget stop scrolling?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to start a process only when the gallery stop scrolling. "onItemSelected" doesn't cut it as it will be called continuously as if scroll by.

So how to detect or callback when the gallery stop scrolling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can tune the behaviour of the [galleryview](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) a little bit with calling [setCallbackDuringFling(false)](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setCallbackDuringFling%28boolean%29). This should limit the calls to `onItemSelected` to cases where the user stopped scrolling.