# Detect when gallery stops scrolling?

Tags: android

I need to start a process when the gallery stops scrolling.
How can I detect or callback when the gallery stops scrolling?

Comment: there is a function "onScrollEnded".. Can u check that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know when gallery widget stop scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733798/how-to-know-when-gallery-widget-stop-scrolling)

Answer (score 3):

You could set callback on fling to false

```
gallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false)
```

When the scrolling stops, the onItemSelected method of the associated OnItemSelectedListener will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) and check if the position of an element is at the same place or some other indicator that the view is not moving anymore and put your actions in there. Good luck!

@Farhan I did't see an onScrollEnded method in the reference.