# how can I kong when gallery is start scroll and stop scroll

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-scroll

I had a gallery and I rewrite it from gallery in *Android source code*.

Now i wanna get the start and stop state of it, how can I do this?

I just wanna know **when did gallery start and stop**, so I can make my animation start stop correctly!

Comment: Can u just explain why u require to find out the stop state of your Gallery's animation?

Comment: I think you didn't know my question well...I had an animation,it isn't gallery's animation.Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tune the behaviour of the galleryview a litlle bit with calling setCallbackDuringFling(false). This should limit the calls to onItemSelected to cases where the user stopped scrolling.

Check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733798/how-to-know-when-gallery-widget-stop-scrolling)

Comment: I tried that void and it could let me know when it stop scroll,but I can't know when it start...any other choice?